# How dynamically create / generate prototypical objects in ES6?

Tags: javascript, model, ecmascript-6

In backbone'js there is a model object in which you can set attributes and extend through a function and will return a new prototype that you can use.

See the first example:

```
var Human = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        alert("Welcome to this world");
    }
});

var human = new Human();
```

Source: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-model

I am trying to achieve this in ES6, but am lacking a in-depth understanding of javascript prototypes.

I have written something which allows this:

```
var Model = {
    foo() {
        return 'bar';
    },
    extend(object) {
        var Extend = function() {

            // Set prototype's schema
            this.schema = object.schema;

            // Inherit model's functions
            this.foo = Model.foo;
        }
        return Extend;
    }
}

// Extend model and create a new prototype
var Human = Mode.extend({
    schema: {
        name: 'string',
        age:  'number'
    }
});

var human1 = new Human();
var human2 = new Human();

console.log( human1.foo() ); // bar
console.log( human1.schema ); // { name: 'string', age: 'number' }
console.log( human2.schema ); // { name: 'string', age: 'number' }
```

I want to use a concept like this to achieve what backbone.js is achieving but in es6. Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:
Sorry I should have clarified, I need it to be prototypical for backwards compatibility. This is going to be a small library where you do not need to use ES6 or classes. I just want to write the library in es6. Users of the library should be able to construct new model prototypes through a extend function.

Comment: ES6 is just a superset of ES5. So what exactly do you mean by _"achieve this in ES6"_? What's particularly confusing is the statement afterwards: _"This is going to be a small library where you do not need to use ES6"_. Now do you want to use ES6 or not, and what features of it?

Answer (score 1):

ECMAScript 6 (a.k.a. ECMAScript 2015) has introduced a Class definition syntax that will look very much like other OOP class structures in that they provide for inheritance and easy access to base-class objects.

However the JavaScript classes introduced are, to quote from the [MDN website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) "syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax is not introducing a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript. JavaScript classes provide a much simpler and clearer syntax to create objects and deal with inheritance."

This is all very welcome in my opinion - syntactical sugar or not.

Biggest issue at the moment is the lack of supporting browsers. But if you are committed to taking advantage of E6 then you should look into this new syntax.

The MDN site also has a wealth of information on prototypical inheritance.

Comment: I am trying to extend through a function so I can package this up into a lib and without es6. It's a bit confusing why I might want this, but the end goal is to be able to extend the prototype through a function.

Comment: It would probably also help to mention that users unable to use ES6, but still wanting to use the library, can use tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to convert code using the class syntax to an ES5-compatible one — without loosing any of its semantics and capabilities.

Comment: Right, but that would add a layer of complexity to using this the library that I could solve in this manner. Eventually when ES6 is the standard, I would be trashing the extend function.

Answer (score 0):

IF it's ES6 then use classes

```
class Alien {
    constructor(type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    role() {
        if (this.type === "Evil") {
            console.log("To destroy the earth and enslave the humans");
        } else {
            console.log("To make crop circles and appear in blurry tabloid photos.");
        }
    }
}

class SciFi extends Alien {
    role() {
        if (this.type === "Evil") {
            console.log("To destroy the rebel alliance.");
        } else {
            console.log("To phone home.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I need it to be prototypical for backwards compatibility. This is going to be a small library where you do not need to use ES6 or classes. I just want to write the library in es6.

Comment: It is not possible to write something in ES6 that is backward compatible.  You can however write something in ES5 that is forward compatible with ES6, ES7 and fingers crossed, ES8.